# Can't open Netlogo files on web in the user community models

Tags: javascript, java, netlogo

In the link below:

http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/community/Water_Cycle_MSU

I would like to use "run this model in your browser"

However, when I click on it, nothing shows up. Can anyone tell me why or how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

That page is using Java applets to try to present the model.  NetLogo might technically still support Java applets, but in general they suffer from [poor support and serious security concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet#Disadvantages).

NetLogo Web is an alternative you can use that does work in the browser, but you will have to download the `Water_Cycle_MSU.nlogo` file from that page and then upload it to [NetLogo Web](https://netlogoweb.org/launch) to try it out.

If you need a permanent place to post a NetLogo model online that'll work in the browser without the download/upload steps, you might check out the [NetLogo Modeling Commons](http://modelingcommons.org/), which does use NetLogo Web to present the models.  There are also [steps to self-host a NetLogo Web model in the NetLogo Web FAQ](https://netlogoweb.org/info#hosting-nlw-files).